# SparkML Vectors: Accessing Model Output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to access values that seem to be locked away in vectors that are returned by model objects. I've seen some posts here and there about old/new Vector types, but that hasn't helped me figure out what I'm missing.

The code from the CountVectorizer model sets up the problem. Seems to have something to do with org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT, but I'm not sure. I've been blocked by this to the point where it's a bit embarrassing.

Can someone please provide a code sample that shows how to parse out each of the 3 elements of the `features` vector: vocabulary count, term id list, term count list?

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{CountVectorizer, CountVectorizerModel}

sc.version
res1: String = 2.1.1

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, Array("a", "b", "c")),
  (1, Array("a", "b", "b", "c", "a"))
)).toDF("id", "words")

// fit a CountVectorizerModel from the corpus
val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = (new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .setVocabSize(3)
  .setMinDF(2)
  .fit(df)
)

// alternatively, define CountVectorizerModel with a-priori vocabulary
val cvm = (new CountVectorizerModel(Array("a", "b", "c"))
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("features")
)

val df_vectorized = cvModel.transform(df)

df_vectorized.show(false)

+---+---------------+-------------------------+
|id |words          |features                 |
+---+---------------+-------------------------+
|0  |[a, b, c]      |(3,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|1  |[a, b, b, c, a]|(3,[0,1,2],[2.0,2.0,1.0])|
+---+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried and succeeded trying to solve your problem !

Comment: @eliasah, thanks for the feedback. I tried a lot of things. I'd rather not clutter up the question with all of my failed attempts. I feel like the solution is something trivial and I'm just not seeing it. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

I found a way to access the data in this particular model.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector

df_vectorized.select("features").rdd.map(_.getAs[SparseVector](0).size).take(2)
df_vectorized.select("features").rdd.map(_.getAs[SparseVector](0).indices).take(2)
df_vectorized.select("features").rdd.map(_.getAs[SparseVector](0).values).take(2)
```

I don't know if it is the best way to achieve such a simple thing.

#### Thoughts

I'd rather do something like the following:

```
case class MyData(
  id: Int,
  words: Array[String],
  features: (Int, Array[Int], Array[Double])
)

df_vectorized.as[MyData]
```

But when I tried this, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
```

Even that isn't great because the elements of the *features* tuple wouldn't be named in that case.

Anyway, I think the take away here is that you need to identify the data type that the model puts out and hope that it has access methods associated with it.

Even identifying the data type was luck. I happened to try the following:

```
df_vectorized.select("features").rdd.map(_.getAs[Seq[Any]](0).size).take(2)
```

And got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector cannot be cast to scala.collection.SeqLike
```

Note that the class of the output was being called a **VectorUDT** when I tried to create a DataSet, but is now being called a **SparseVector** when I use the RDD api.

So thats how I found the right data type. Which was really annoying because the relevant output of `df_vectorized.schema` is *org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7*.

For an additional headache, the description of VectorUDT reads: *User-defined type for Vector which allows easy interaction with SQL via org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset*. Maybe it does allow for 'easy' interaction. I can't seem to figure that out though.

Comment: I figured out an approach to solve my problem. I'll let this answer hang here a bit incase anyone has a better solution.